# Display UI from external website in Google Apps editor add on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I am working on an add on for google (specifically docs at this point) to allow users to insert content into their document. Either as text or an image (png). The content would come from my site, where users have created the content, and would be displayed in the sidebar of the editor.

In order to do this they need to authenticate to our site (oAuth), so that the list of their projects (thumbnail images) can be displayed in the sidebar, from which they can select and insert into their document.

I have not been able to find anything within the google add on documentation (other than possibly using urlFetch), and not sure if this is something that would even be allowed.

(The other thought I had was to use urlFetch to call a rest endpoint which would return JSON to populate the sidebar UI, as opposed to being able to display existing UI)

Answer (score 0):

You can include images in your add-on from third party sites without needing OAuth.

Just choosing a random example on the web, like the logo from the [Wayback Machine website](https://archive.org/web/), https://archive.org/web/images/logo_wayback_210x77.png, you can add to your add-on. Really any image online will work as long as it's a PNG file.

Example JSON, when I type this into https://gw-card-builder.web.app/ it works fine:

> {   "sections": [
> {
> "widgets": [
> {
> "image": {
> "imageUrl": "https://archive.org/web/images/logo_wayback_210x77.png",
> "altText": "Example image",
> "onClick": {
> "openLink": {
> "url": "https://archive.org"
> }
> }
> }
> }
> ]
> }   ] }